# How can I perform this join on a table with multiple records per key without returning multiple records per key?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have three tables that I need to join together, tableA, tableB, and tableC.

tableA and tableB get joined together on the field 'userid', and tableC gets joined on 'numeric_id'.

My problem is that there are multiple records in tableC for each numeric_id. How can I limit the query by a distinct list of numeric_id?

This query returns 23 rows, as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB 
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'AS432'
AND tableA.userid = tableB.userid
```

This query returns 52 rows, because each numeric_id has multiple records in tableC

```
SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB,tableC
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'AS432'
AND tableA.userid = tableB.userid
AND tableB.numeric_id = tableC.numeric_id
```

How can I perform this join without returning multiple records per numeric_id in tableC?

Example data:

```
tableA:
userid        first_name
jsamsonite    John
sjohnson      Sam
hpulaski      Harry
```

tableB:

```
userid      last_name numeric_id
jsamsonite  Samsonite 56 
sjohnson    Johnson   57
hpulaski    Pulaski   58
```

tableC:

```
numeric_id transaction_number region_group
56           56345            789
56           89848            789
57           89800            987
57           52355            987
57           49939            987
58           49892            398
```

Ideally the query would return

```
tableA.userid tableA.first_name tableB.userid tableB.last_name tableB.numeric_ID tableC.numeric_id tableC.region_group
jsamsonite    John               jsamsonite    Samsonite   56    56    789
sjohnson      Sam                sjohnson      Johnson     57    57    987
hpulaski      Harry              Hpulaski      Pulaski     58    58    398
```

Comment: What values are you after in C?  There's a reason C contains duplicates. 
 or are all the values you're after from C duplicate?  You could join using (Select Distinct col1, col2, Numeric_ID from tableC) instead of just tableC assuming col1, col2 and numeric_ID would be consistent for each record; and thereby eliminate the duplication.  Or are you just using C as a filter you only want records in C having a numeric_ID? if that's the case then you should use an exists.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Updated with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an exists if you're just limiting the data instead of needing columns from c?  instead of a join?

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'AS432'
  AND tableA.userid = tableB.userid
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablec WHERE tableB.numeric_id = tableC.numeric_id)
```

or just select the columns needed that are duplicated and use distinct

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB, (SELECT DISTINCT col1, Col2, numeric_ID from tablec) tablec
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'AS432'
  AND tableA.userid = tableB.userid
  AND tableB.numeric_id = tableC.numeric_id)
```

Or using modern join syntax... ANSI-92 standards. but still with a distinct on a subquery with like column values from c.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
  on  tableA.userid = tableB.userid
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col1, Col2, numeric_ID from tablec) tablec
  on  tableB.numeric_id = tableC.numeric_id
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = 'AS432'
```

Comment: I updated with some sample data and expected result, if you don't mind re-examining it.

Comment: Your second solution was what I was looking for.

Comment: I agree, I just now noticed your comment.  Though the 3rd query should work as well.  Just depends if your an ANSI-87 shop or a ANSI-92 shop.